# Why my code does not work without window.addEventListener("load" , start) in javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am new to JavaScript. In the code snippet below, I'm trying to understand what window.addEventListener("load", start) does. I searched online to learn more about event listeners, but I still don't understand them. Could anyone explain how event listeners work and how parameters passed to them are used? Thank you for your help. I know this is a very beginner's question.

***My JavaScript Code***

```js
function start() {
  var n1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  var total1 = 0;
  var total2 = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < n1.length; ++i) {
    total1 += n1[i];
  }

  var res = "<p>Total using indices :" + total1 + "</p>";

  for (var element in n1) {
    total2 += n1[element];
  }

  res += "<br><p> total using for..in:" + total2 + "</p>";

  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = res;
}

window.addEventListener("load", start); // <- This is the line that I am referring to
```

Comment: It waits for the page to load. I guess that without this you are trying to access not-loaded-yet elements

Comment: Put your script on end of page ( end of body) and then you don't have to wait for load you can instead just call your function start()

Comment: Just declare ',output1' element before defind your script. Then when script function will run it will have access to output 1. If you declare script before html then you can run your function when Html will be loaded. That's why you have to wait

Answer (score 0):

It waits for the whole page to load and starts the script after the all elements of the page are loaded.
And you can also put your `<script>` at the end of the HTML code and just call `start()` so you don't need `window.addEventListener("load", start);`.

---

Learn more about `addEventListner`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

> The `addEventListener()` method of the [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) interface sets up a function that will be called whenever the specified event is delivered to the target.